# Initialising PageFactory just once in a separate java class

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I am trying to reduce the verbosity in my script, following the Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY) coding practice. I stumbled on a challenge. I have implemented a basic test using selenium and cucumber with pagefactory. I have my page objects in one separate `BasePage` class and initialised pagefactory in another `Test` class. The initialisation is taking place inside every method and the test runs as expected.

```
public class Test {
private static WebDriver driver;

public void navigateToUrl(String url) {
//Launch browser
}

public void firstLogin(String username, String Password) {
BasePage basePage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, BasePage.class); //Initialisation
basePage.usernameField.click();
basePage.passwordField.sendKeys("pwd");
}

public void secondLogin()  {
BasePage basePage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, BasePage.class); //Initialisation
basePage.myIdField.click();
basePage.myPasswordField.click();    
}
```

I am trying to enhance the script. I want to initialise pagefactory just once, perhaps at class level, and not initialise inside every method, so, I took off the initialisation from all the methods and declared it once at class level:

```
public class Test {
private static WebDriver driver;
BasePage basePage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, BasePage.class); //Initialisation
```

I got a nullpointerException.

I also tried this, putting the initialisation in a setup method:

```
public class Test {
private static WebDriver driver;
private static BasePage basePage;

@BeforeMethod
public void setUp() {
basePage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, BasePage.class);
}
```

Still, It resulted in Nullpointer

My `BasePage` header looks like this:

```
public class BasePage {
private final WebDriver driver;

public BasePage(WebDriver driver) {
   this.driver = driver;
  }
```

Not only am I initialising multiple times, I am also using the `basePage` variable in every line in the `firstLogin` and `secondLogin` methods. Whether there is a way round that, I dont know, but it would be helpful if someone can advise or give an input. Thanks.

Comment: How and when are you initializing the driver?

Comment: The driver is initialised with a constructor inside the BasePage class for pagefactory, this way:  `public BasePage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
  }`

Comment: And when is this constructor called by Test class

Comment: It is initialised in the `BasePage` with this: `private final WebDriver driver;` I have added the `BasePage` header to the question

Comment: Place this line `PageFactory.initElements(driver, BasePage.class);` in the BasePage constructor.

Comment: No luck. Immediately I put the line in the constructor, all the `basePage` variables in Test class turned red

Comment: @Theman did you get a solution to this?

Comment: @KumarSourav, yes I got a solution. Thanks

Comment: @Theman can you post it here ?